# Concerns about rust in garage workshop

Tags: table-saw, tool-maintenance, rust

I am just getting into woodworking. My garage is the only place I can set up a workshop. The weather in my area ranges from cold winters to hot, humid summers. I'm concerned about rust developing on tools (table saw, jointer,...). Should I be concerned? Do woodworkers take steps to prevent rust, or are the tools already "rust-proof" (assuming I'm not going to leave a glass of ice water sitting on something for days)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I store hand tools so they won't rust?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/67/how-can-i-store-hand-tools-so-they-wont-rust) Also this, [Table saw top treatment](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1476/table-saw-top-treatment/1484#1484) and a few other Q&As here touch on the topic, both from a prevention and cure perspective.

Comment: The "How can I store hand tools so they won't rust" page did not answer my question. But the second one mentioned, "Table saw top treatment" is super relevant and helps a lot. Thanks!

Comment: This is also very broad and opinion based. "Should I be concerned?" Well, yes, you probably should, but some aren't. If you've got extra cash, just buy new tools when the old ones get rusty... "Do woodworkers take steps...?" Yes, some do, no others do not. That's the only possible way to answer those questions...

Comment: @FreeMan I took "Should I be concerned?" coming after "I'm concerned about..." to mean "Is there a reasonable basis for my concern, or am I worrying about something that's not really a problem?" In that sense, I don't think the question is very subjective.

Comment: Maybe I'm applying [diy.se] standards here and shouldn't be, @Caleb. As little traffic as we get, I shouldn't be discouraging questions... My bad.

Comment: @FreeMan Sounds like Home Improvement is where the action is! In any case, it's certainly open to interpretation, and I just interpreted it a little differently.

Comment: @FreeMan, *"As little traffic as we get, I shouldn't be discouraging questions... My bad."* Er, not so much. What's written in the Help and Tour is what it is, quiet or not some of that is firm and e.g. we shouldn't answer bad Questions. (And for that matter nobody should be upvoting Qs that show **absolutely zero** research either, but that's a can of worms I've chosen not to get into in Meta.... although I've been tempted.)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm concerned about rust developing on tools (table saw, jointer,...). Should I be concerned?

**Yes.** Preventing rust is a constant battle in some climates. The combination of humid air and large swings in temperature make it easy for moisture to condense on cold surfaces such as cast iron tables.

> Do woodworkers take steps to prevent rust

**Yes,** many do; preventing rust a frequent topic of discussion and debate in woodworking forums. There are many strategies for combatting rust. The best (IMO) is to set up your shop in a space with climate control, thus avoiding large changes in both temperature and humidity. If that's not possible, other ways to prevent rust are to cover the most rust-prone surfaces or to coat them with something. Some people use moving blankets or magnetic covers to minimize contact with moist air when the tools aren't being used. There are a variety of possible coatings, but one of the most popular is some form of wax. Paste wax and sprays containing wax can work; avoid automotive waxes that contain silicone. There are about as many opinions as to which method/product is best as there are woodworkers.

Comment: This is a dupe Caleb as already acknowledged by the OP. Duplicates (as well as bad Qs, *which this also is*) shouldn't be answered.

Comment: @Graphus The OP's questions seem quite distinct from the ones you linked, and IMO deserving of an answer even if it's related to some others.

Comment: OK put aside whether this is distinct enough, obviously that's open to some interpretation. But what isn't is that we have to do what we can to prevent being seen as a "here let me Google that for you" service.